# Code is returning an incorrect number of days in calendar

Tags: ios, calendar, nsdate

I am making a calendar for practicing purposes and I am trying to find the number of days in a particular month of a particular year.

I was successful in finding the proper values until today, when suddenly I am not getting the correct number of days for february only. It was working fine earlier and I made no changes of any kind to my code.

My code:

```
-(NSDate *)startOfMonth:(NSInteger)calendarMonth :(NSInteger)calendarYear
{
    NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
    NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents * comps = [calendar components: NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:date];

    [comps setMonth:calendarMonth];

    [comps setYear:calendarYear];

    NSDate * monthOnlyDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSDateComponents * currentDateComponents = [calendar components:     NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:monthOnlyDate ];

    self.numberOfDays = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay inUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth forDate:monthOnlyDate].length ;

    NSLog(@"NUMBER OF DAYS==%li",(long)self.numberOfDays);

    NSDate * startOfAnyMonth = [calendar dateFromComponents: currentDateComponents];
    NSDateFormatter *weekDay = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [weekDay setDateFormat:@"EEE"];
    NSString * currentDay =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[weekDay stringFromDate:startOfAnyMonth]];
    [self updateFirstDateOFCurrentMonth:currentDay];
    return startOfAnyMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the reason it was working a few days ago and isn't working today for February is that February doesn't have a 30th day (which is today), and you're creating the date object based on the current day and then changing the month, without checking the day.

But more than that, your logic isn't quite clear to me - If what you're going for is getting the first day of the specified month, why not just create the NSDate object based on the components specified by the user, while providing 1 as the value for the day component? What you're doing here is creating a date based on today, changing the components and then checking them to get values that you set manually (and therefore already know).

Also, if this is for practicing purposes, as you mentioned, I would highly recommend providing names for all of the parameters as part of the method declarations, otherwise calling it would be less readable. In this case, I would consider changing the method name to:

```
- (NSDate *)startOfMonth:(NSInteger)calendarMonth ofYear:(NSInteger)calendarYear
```

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Great,it worked.Thanks a lot.And I'll start using the method declaration with parameters name.

Comment: I am trying to get day for first of month by passing month and year.